# Vanishing line on Conway's game of life

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, combinatorial-game-theory, cellular-automata

If the initial state of [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is a line of $n \in [0,100]$ alive cells, then it vanishes completely after some steps iff $n \in \{0,1,2,6,14,15,18,19,23,24 \}$. See below for $n=24$.
[image]

*Question*: Is such a line non-vanishing for any $n \in [25,\infty)$?

**Edit**

*Definition*: a finite pattern $p$ has a *weak period* $wp$ if for any cell $c$ in the grid, there is $k>0$ such that the set of cells which are neighbours of neighbours of neighbours... ($k$ times) of $c$, is periodic of period $wp$ after sufficiently many generations, from the initial state $p$.

The sequence [A061342](https://oeis.org/A061342) gives the weak period $wp_n$ of a line of $n$ alive cells. By combining the checking above with the fact that $wp_n \ge 2$ for $n \in [84,1000]$, we deduce that the pattern is non-vanishing for $n \in [25,1000]$. We observe that for $n=500$, four [gliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(Conway%27s_Life)) are produced on the boundaries after $435$ steps, but $435<500$, so this must happens $\forall n \ge 500$. *Assuming* that these gliders (or others) are perpetual (as stated *implicitly* by Nathaniel Johnston in [A061342](https://oeis.org/A061342), although without reference, while the proof could be non-trivial, as pointed out by Will Sawin in the comments), the answer to the above question would be **yes**.

*Definition*: a finite pattern $p$ is *weakly-vanishing* if any cell $c$ in the grid becomes perpetually dead after sufficiently many generations (depending on $c$), from the initial state $p$.

**Improved question**: Is there a weakly-vanishing line of $n$ alive cells with $n \in [25,\infty)$?

*Stronger question*: Is $wp_n \ge 2$ for any $[84,\infty)$ ?

---

Tobias Fritz pointed out in the comments that there is a one-cell thick pattern with infinite growth (see [this page](http://www.conwaylife.com/w/index.php?title=One_cell_thick_pattern)), but it is disconnected. *Bonus question*: Can that happen in the connected case?

Comment: Is your question about all $n>24$ or just $n\in[25,100]$? Also, you state "iff", but are the non-vanishing instances actually known? (e.g. eventually periodic)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: for $n \in [0,100]$ I have checked that the vanishing happens iff $n \in \{0,1,2,6,14,15,18,19,23,24 \}$. The question is about $n>24$ (and so $n>100$ after my checking).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: $n=10$ produces a pattern of period $15$, but that's not the point of this question.

Comment: What do you mean by _stationary component_? Do you know that the pattern can be decomposed for long times into gliders/spaceships plus something that happens in a bounded region? This is not always the case, e.g. there even are patterns that grow quadratically (http://pentadecathlon.com/lifeNews/2011/05/quadratic_population_growth_fr.html).

Comment: @TobiasFritz: according to [this page](http://www.conwaylife.com/w/index.php?title=One_cell_thick_pattern), infinite growth has been discovered for a one-cell thick pattern which is disconnected. I don't know if it is possible in the connected case (i.e. "with all cells alive", which is *implicitly* the case for this question), but it is an interesting problem.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: so whether infinite growth is impossible in your case is part of the question? Assuming that it is indeed impossible, how is the stationary component defined? In terms of periodicity?

Comment: @TobiasFritz: your comments are helpful, thanks! One can certainly define the stationary component in terms of periodicity, but I have better with the following: a pattern is called *weakly-vanishing* if any cell becomes perpetually dead after some generations (depending on the cell). I will improve the post with this new notion.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Aha, nice!

Comment: How do you know the gliders are perpetual? Couldn't something else catch up and stop them? Or can you rule that out?

Comment: @WillSawin: you are right, this glider (of speed $c/4$) could be catch up for example by a Lightweight spaceship (of speed $c/2$). Off the top of my head, I cannot rule that out, but Nathaniel Johnston should be able to. It is a nice problem! Anyway, the new notion of "weakly-vanishing" (I will improve the post with) allows to avoid this problem.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux LWSS cannot catch up to a glider, since a glider goes diagonally, whereas LWSS goes horizontally.

Comment: @Wojowu: A horizontal line can cross a diagonal line. Perhaps the word "catch up" is not suitable, "destroy" could be better.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux In order to destroy a diagonal spaceship using c/2 horizontal/vertical movement, we would have to first move a certain distance vertically, and then a similar distance horizontally. Working this out shows that we have moved diagonally at, effectively, c/4 speed. Unless you have a more specific idea of how a glider could be destroyed like that, I don't see how it's possible.

Comment: @Wojowu: the LWSS can be created higher than the glider.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: $n=41, 96, 102$ creates a perpetual pulsar, toad, spark coil (respectively). For $n \in [1,100]$, a perpetual glider appears iff $n \in \{ 56, 71, 75,78, 82, 85, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 98\}$. I know that there are always four "escaping" gliders created at generation $435$ for $n \ge 500$ (and this bound can certainly be improved to $n \ge 145$), but I don't know if there are perpetual, in particular I cannot rule out that for some $n$ they can be destroy by something quicker. This is relevant for the question but not for the *improved* question.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I deleted my comment as too careless. So maybe then it is a sensible conjecture that the "pseudolimit" only can contain gliders, constant configurations and periodic areas of period 2 and 15?

Comment: Btw the growth speed in the perpendicular direction is initially c, so there is indeed plenty of time to generate c/2 spaceships to destroy all gliders in sight...

Answer (score 6):

Just to help develop intuition - here is a fragment of a typical evolution for large $n$ (made with [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/))

[image]

Comment: I presume that this is large (size) $n$ and large (time) $t$. But does this screen shot correspond to $n$ and $t$ of comparable size? Or are we looking here at a case of $0<<n<<t$?

Comment: @AndréHenriques To my shame I did not record exact numbers, but your last suggestion is correct: $n$ is around $23000$ and $t$ is around 2 million.

Comment: The first glider produced (at $t=435$, visible here at extreme left) did not exceed the half high of the pyramid,  so here $t$ must be less than $23000$.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Sorry for messing things up, maybe the number I remember was population count (printed out next to the generation count).

Comment: It should be straightforward to prove that this Sierpinski triangle pattern continues to be generated for arbitrarily large lines of live cells (and therefore that the answer to the original question is yes). The only potential issue is the case analysis needed to handle what happens when the two Sierpinskis growing from either end meet at the middle of the line.

Comment: @DavidEppstein There seems to be one more issue: the symmetric clouds of debris trapped inside (containing some gliders too) may in principle cause disturbances which can be qualitatatively different near the horizontal axis for some $n$.

Comment: If you try big enough starting lines (I tried around 500,000) you can see that the lines down the middles of each big triangular void (where the gliders meet) eventually become periodic. In the image above, the biggest complete triangles appear to have about three periods within them.

Comment: @DavidEppstein: [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289810/the-1-step-vanishing-polyplets-on-conways-game-of-life/289865#comment718512_289865) suggests that your algorithm can easily classify the $1$-step vanishing $n$-polyplets for small $n$. Do you have them?

Comment: The "extra pruning rules to reject patterns that are disconnected" part is not completely obvious, because connectivity is not really purely local (things that look disconnected from each other in one neighborhood could really be connected via paths outside that neighborhood).

Comment: @DavidEppstein: FYI, I replied to your comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289810/the-1-step-vanishing-polyplets-on-conways-game-of-life/289865#comment719544_289865) (to avoid fragmenting the discussion too much).